# How to remove duplicates in nested lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I want to remove both duplicates and permutations from my nested list.

Input:

```
[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 2, -1], [-1, 2, -1], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

Expected Output:

```
[[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 2, -1]]
```

I tried using a list comprehension but I end up with the output as

```
[[-1, 1, 0], [-1, 2, -1], [-1, 0, 1], [-1, -1, 2]]
```

Here is what I attempted.

```
a = [[-1, 0, 1], [-1, 1, 0], [-1, 2, -1], [-1, 2, -1], [-1, -1, 2]]
b_set = set(tuple(x) for x in a)
b = [ list(x) for x in b_set ]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is expected because `[-1, 0, 1] != [-1, 1, 0]`. You can sort the inner tuples if you want to make sure that they are considered equal:

```
b_set = set(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or with `map`:

```
b_set = set(map(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)),a))
```